# Lyrics from a P!nk Song?

Tags: cipher

The subject line is a clue, but you’ll need to find where. Additional clue: look up. Or down, maybe.

I have to admit the answer isn’t very rewarding. Sorry about that; it’s more a proof of concept right now.

```
1333827A050448R07
2215210A525246R04
2431121B010024R02
3451848A592243R02
3011459B485802R06
2131036B532515R10
1040455A393616R06
```

Clues:

1. > Stars
2. > Positions
3. > First

Comment: Anyone? Come on, this is an easy one…

Comment: It took a year and a half for somebody to solve your last one. :)

Comment: Are you calling me Master? :-p

Comment: Yeah, I think I got that much from your bio already. :P Am I supposed to use SIMBAD for this? It keeps coming back with "No object found".

Comment: Yes and no. Think outside the box a bit.

Comment: But you’re on the good path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each string is

> the position of a star, with “A” for south (*austral*) and “B” for north (*boreal*), in **ecliptic** positions. After the “R” is the **r**ank of a letter in its IAU name.

For the first one, we have

> 2215210A525246R04
>  So its position if λ = 221° 52′ 10″ and β = 52° 52′ 46″, which is the star Alpha Crucis, common name Acrux. Fourth letter is U.

I realize now that there was an error in the puzzle, as

> the first star was supposed to have S. I guess some lines were mixed.

Anyway, the letters end up spelling

> SUCCESS.

Comment: So which P!nk lyric was the title referring to in all this?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail how you arrive at each of those seven letters (or six, bearing in mind the mistake in the puzzle)? And as Stiv said, can you explain how the title fits in with this?

Comment: When I was editing your clues into the question, I found the missing line @pierre. When using four backticks to make coffee formatting, anything you put on the line with the first four backticks is hidden. (The parser interprets it as a language hint)

Comment: @Stiv and bobble: Very obscure reference to her song “Just Give Me a Reason,” in which she says “It’s in the stars.” I guess I might have heard her song not long before posting the puzzle.

Comment: @F1Krazy: As I said in my answer, the number after “R” in each line is the rank of the letter in the star name. 1333827A050448R07 is Alpha Cancri, also called Acubens. R07 means seventh letter, so the S. Etc.